# How to use something similar of LinkPoke in C#?

Tags: c#, vb6-migration, dde

I want to replace an existing program which sends signals to my [RSLinx](http://www.rockwellautomation.com/rockwellsoftware/products/rslinx.page). I'm looking into replacing it with C#.

I've decompiled this program (a VB6 application) and found it uses some methods which are not immediately available in C#: [LinkMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235154(v=vs.60).aspx) and [LinkPoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa244124(v=vs.60).aspx).

How do I replace the functionality of these method calls when using C#?

Answer (score 2):

The linkmode technology DDE which was used in VB, is no longer supported. In C# .net, you can try **DDEML**. [Check this link for DDEML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648712(v=vs.85).aspx).

It is a new technology and there is no simple way to just replace a keyword to another keyword or something like that.

Comment: Utsav Dawn, thanks, but is there any guide about how to do the same action in DDEML? I know that there is no simple way to just replace a keyword, but any guide about how to do it?